# How to setup real time ETW session with remote machine

Tags: etw

I have requirements of monitoring performance of one windows machine (Device under test) from another (host device).

I am planning to setup real time ETW logging on device under test.
Write a ETW realtime consumer application (console) which would collect the events in real time but instead of processing it on test device, simply transfer it to host device wherein they can be processed.

So far we followed consumer example and able to receive callback every 1 sec
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364157(v=vs.85).aspx

The example talks about processing event in place, however we want to transfer it to remote machine for processing. How can I transfer the raw real time buffer/data from PEVENT_TRACE structure?

Comment: You want to use a programming language for that or can you use built-on tools from Windows?

Comment: Are there windows tools doing this already? Please share the details.